# Show that by Newton’s Law of Cooling, the time required to cool an object from temperature A to temperature B is

Tags: calculus

a) Show that by Newton’s Law of Cooling, the time required to cool an object from temperature A to temperature B is

$$t = \frac{1}{k} \ln\frac{B-T}{A-T}$$

where $T$s is the temperature of the surroundings and $k$ is the cooling constant ($k < 0$).

(b) During the early morning following Halloween you just happened to come across a fully functioning locked freezer in
an alley. Curious about its contents you broke open the door and found a dead body inside. When you found the body the
temperature was $30^\circ$C. Assuming a human corpse obeys Newton’s Law of Cooling with cooling constant $-0.012 \text{ hour}^{-1},$ and the temperature in the freezer is $-15^\circ$C, estimate how long ago the person died? (Assume the temperature of a living body is $98.6^\circ\text{F} = 37^\circ\text{C}.$) (Hint: Use the result in part (a).)

Comment: Edit the question to show what you tried and where are stuck. Then you may get some help. Please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: In part (b) all you need to do is plug in the numbers you're given in place of $k,$ $B,$ $A,$ and $T. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, thank you for your reply. If possible, can you explain question A for me? and also I dont know what to put for b,a and T. English is my second language and I am struggling to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $S$ is the temperature of the object at time $t.$ The Newton's law of cooling says
$$
S-T = (S_0 - T) e^{-kt}
$$
where $S_0$ is the temperature when $t=0.$ Let $t_A$ and $t_B$ be the times at which the temperature is $A$ and $B$ respectively. Then you have
\begin{align}
& A-T = (S_0-T)e^{-kt_A} \\[5pt]
& B-T = (S_0-T)e^{-kt_B} \\[8pt]
\text{Therfore } & \frac{B-T}{A-T} = e^{-k(t_B-t_A)} \\[8pt]
\text{So } & \ln \frac{B-T}{A-T} = -k(t_B-t_A) = k(t_A-t_B)
\end{align}
etc.